# Trying to combine multiple queries into one query

Tags: php, mysql

*Note, if you can think of a more constructive title, please do edit.

---

I have a table that looks like this:

```
   id   |   forGame    |   otherType    |   otherName    |   otherDesc
9       |+Stellar+Dawn |Character       |Car             |Car
10      |+Stellar+Dawn |Item            |Brugson Burson  |a guy
11      |+Stellar+Dawn |Item            |Space Pie       |A pie from space
```

Now, my problem is that I'm trying to seperate multiple queries into one:

```
$gameOther_typeItem = $database->queryDB("SELECT * FROM `mainSite_others` WHERE otherType='Item' AND forGame='$gameName'");
$gameOther_typeEntity = $database->queryDB("SELECT * FROM `mainSite_others` WHERE otherType='Entity' AND forGame='$gameName'");
$gameOther_typeCharacter = $database->queryDB("SELECT * FROM `mainSite_others` WHERE otherType='Character' AND forGame='$gameName'");
```

(Don't worry about the $database->... part, that's my class.)

---

How might I combine these into one?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is "`OR`".

Comment: you have it all backwards, several in to one. Not one in to multiple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use "`OR'".

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column1 = value1 AND column3 = value3 OR column2 = value2 AND column3 = value3
```

Or, you could use multiple query to execute multiple queries at the same time?

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM `mainSite_others` WHERE (otherType='Item' OR otherType =
>   'Entity' OR otherType = 'Character') AND forGame='$gameName';